# What's the answer of this limit?

Tags: limits

Given that

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\ xf(x)-4}{x-2}=3,$$

find

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ \frac { f\left( x \right) -2 }{ \sqrt { x-1 } -1 }  } =?\quad $$

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: If the first limit is known to be 3, and the second limit is known as well, what are you supposed to "find"? The limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to 2$?

Comment: What do you suggest to edit The title ?

Comment: @upvoter Please explain your vote on a question completely lacking of context.

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: Still wrong ? @Did

Comment: What? @MCCCS's answer? Very much so, I am afraid. But don't you know?

Comment: @SuheirAlSabbah Second answer accepted without having been read?

Comment: The (new) accepted answer is wrong (again).

Answer (score 4):

The given limit implies that as $x\to2$,
$$\frac{ xf(x)-4}{x-2}=3+o(1)\implies xf(x)=4+3(x-2)+o(x-2).$$
Hence, as $x\to2$,
\begin{align*}
\frac { f\left( x \right) -2 }{ \sqrt { x-1 } -1 }
&=
 \left(\sqrt { x-1 } +1\right) \frac { \frac{xf\left( x \right)}{x} -2 }{ x-2 }\\
&=
\left(\sqrt { x-1 } +1\right) \frac{4+3(x-2)+o(x-2) -2x }{ x(x-2) }\\
&=
\left(\sqrt { x-1 } +1\right) \frac{(x-2)+o(x-2) }{ x(x-2) }\\
&=\left(\sqrt { x-1 } +1\right) \frac{1+o(1) }{ x }\to 1.
\end{align*}

Comment: @Suheir Al Sabbah Any further doubt?

Comment: ...The Power of Landau, in all its magnificence. (+1)

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Robert Z

Comment: Can you explain the final step (the last line) ? @Robert Z

Comment: @Suheir Al Sabbah As $x\to 2$ then $\sqrt { x-1 } +1\to 2$, $1+o(1)\to 1$ and $x\to 2$. $o(1)$ is an infinitesimal as $x\to 2$.

Comment: Yeah yeah thanks a lot @Robert Z

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple. You need to get hold of the expression $f(x) - 2$. The given limit in question can be expressed as $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x(f(x)-2)}{x-2}+2=3$$ or $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x)-2}{x-2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ Now one needs to note that $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{x-1}-1}=\lim_{x\to 2}\sqrt{x-1}+1=2$$ and multiplying the above two limits we get the answer as $1$.

Note that the problem is just an algebraic manipulation of the given limit. Any attempt to assume any extra properties of $f$ like guessing about $f(2)$ or continuity of $f$ etc is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

As $x-2=(\sqrt{x-1}-1)(\sqrt{x-1}+1)$, there will be a factor $2$.

Then you can write

$$xf(x)-4=(x-2)f(x)+2(f(x)-2)$$ and use the fact that $f(2)=2$. (More precisely, tends to $2$.)

Comment: We don't know anything about $f(2)$. The right split is $xf(x) - 4=x(f(x)-2)+2(x-2)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: you do know that $f(2)=2$ because the first limit is finite, hence the numerator must tend to $0$.

Comment: What we know for sure is that $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=2$. Unless we assume continuity it does not give us any information about $f(2)$. And we don't really need to assume continuity of $f$ for this problem. See my solution posted here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: that's a technicality which doesn't influence the final result.

Comment: Then mention that you assume continuity in your solution. And also understand that this assumption is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I added a comment. But again, you are splitting hairs.

Comment: On further analysis even your solution does not require the value of $f(2)$. It only needs the limit of $f$ at $2$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: right, you really misunderstood me upfront.

Comment: Please don't take my feedback in negative manner. I have not given any downvote. And I saw your edit later.

Comment: My point is: this nuance is inessential and it is not worth taking things so literally.